# Object variable or with block variable not set error for creating worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

The code below works fine on its own but once i add option explicit at the start, the object variable or with block variable not set error appears at the sheetname = index3. I have seen other threads where the issue is solved by `set sheetname = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("")` but there are 3 sheets that will be created before i used this statement so i don't think it can work that way. Any ideas to solve this?

```
Option explicit
Private Sub createvramp()
        Static count As Long
        Dim iRow As Long
        Dim aRow As Long
        Dim a As Long
        Dim b As Long
        Dim selectRange As Range
        Dim lastline As Integer
        Dim sheetname As Worksheet
        Dim indexrowcount As Integer


        j = 2
        iRow = 1
        lastline = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
        While iRow < lastline + 1
            a = iRow + 1
            b = iRow + 99 ' Max Group Size with Same name in F to H column
            count = 1
            If Cells(iRow, "H").Value = "Vramp_M1" Then
                sheetname = "Index1"
            ElseIf Cells(iRow, "H").Value = "Vramp_M2" Then
                sheetname = "Index2"
            Else
                sheetname = "Index3" '<-------error occurs here
            End If
            For aRow = a To b
                If Cells(iRow, "H") = Cells(aRow, "H") And Cells(iRow, "I") = Cells(aRow, "I") And Cells(iRow, "J") = Cells(aRow, "J") Then
                    count = count + 1
                Else
                    Set selectRange = Range("A" & iRow & ":AP" & aRow - 1)
                    selectRange.Copy
                    indexrowcount = Sheets(sheetname).UsedRange.Rows.count + 1
                    Sheets(sheetname).Range("A" & indexrowcount).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    iRow = iRow + count
                    Exit For
               End If
            Next aRow
        Wend
```

Comment: You declared `sheetname  As Worksheet` and you want to allocate to such a variable a `String`... If the sheet exists you must use `Set sheetname = WorkSheetes("Index3")`. If you want to create a sheet you must use `Set sheetname = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add` and `sheetname.Name = "Index3"`. If you just want to set **the sheet name** in your code, use `Dim sheetname As String`. `Option Explicit` helps a lot, but you must be very careful when you declare variables...

Comment: @FaneDuru ah i keep thinking sheetname is dim as worksheet. You are right, once i dim it as string, it is solved

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set the sheet name in your code, use `Dim sheetname As String`. `Option Explicit` helps a lot, but you must be very careful when you declare variables...

It happened that the error to appear on that row only because the first two conditions were `False`...

It is also good to avoid using of `ActiveSheet`, `Sheets(...)`, `Range("A" ...)`, `Cells(aRow,...)`.

Everything expressed in this way **refers to ActiveSheet**. When you will work on a different sheet, maybe on a different workbook and you need to process a specific sheet (`Sheets(sheetname).Range...`), you may face a big mess. Try to define the sheet with reference to its workbook. Each range to reference the sheet where it belongs...

At least `Dim Sh as Worksheet` followed by `Set Sh = ActiveSheet` (use your working sheet). And then use `Sh.Range("A...)`, `Sh.Cells(aRow,...)` and so on...

It is recommended to cultivate good habits which will help you in the future...